# CUDA on kernel 5.9

Tags: drivers, nvidia, manjaro, cuda

I tried to install cuda on Manjaro with kernel linux54 and linux59 but did not manage to get it work. I have a 64-bit laptop with Hybrid graphics, my graphic card being a GeForce 950M. My video-driver is `video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-450xx-prime` (I don't think this has an impact though). The nvidia packages/drivers I have are:

```
> pacman -Qqe | grep nvidia
lib32-nvidia-450xx-utils
linux54-nvidia-450xx
linux59-nvidia-450xx
nvidia-450xx-utils
nvidia-prime
```

Here's what I got from `nvidia-smi`:

```
Fri Nov 27 13:46:47 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 950M    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   43C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      3MiB /  2004MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A       797      G   /usr/lib/Xorg                       3MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Furtermore, here's the cuda version I have:

```
> pacmcan -Q cuda
cuda 11.0.3-1
```

Finally, here's what I get when running the `deviceQuery` sample from cuda:

```
> ./deviceQuery
./bin/x86_64/linux/release/deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 999
-> unknown error
Result = FAIL
```

I've seen several articles/posts indicating that CUDA was not supported by kernel 5.9 but they're all from October 2020, and NVIDIA was planning a working driver for 5.9 by mid-November. However, I did not find any posts indicating that the problem was solved. Do I merely need to wait for the nvidia-driver, or is my problem due to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NVIDIA drivers 455.45.01](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/166883/en-us) fully support kernel 5.9. The ones you're using don't support this kernel version.

Please update.